# What is the meaning of the term "image"?

Tags: optics

I know it is where the rays of light cross, but what exactly is it? Why do we perceive it as being where an object is located?

Comment: Can you just provide some image or a bit more information about what exactly you are asking? With a detailed question you will get a precise answer. "Where the rays of light cross" would be a focal point. We perceive the distance because we have two eyes, allowing us to have 3D information.

Comment: The brain is trained to perceive distance to an object from the light rays expanding from that object. You can "trick" the brain by emulating the exact rays as if expanding from another point. An image point is such a case. This analogy works for both real and virtual images.

Comment: If a bundle of rays come from the same point (source) and arrive by some "magic", i.e, optics, projected at the retina in the same spot then you will *see* that source point. That is all.